# Different behaviour with cElementTree and ElementTree

Tags: python-2.7, celementtree

In the below case we do not get same return types.
One is with `Element` and other with `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`

Why is this difference ?

```
 import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET1
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET2
 import multiprocessing

 tree1 = ET1.parse('country_data.xml')
 root1 = tree1.getroot()

 manager1 = multiprocessing.Manager()
 elems_saved1 = manager1.dict()



 tree2 = ET2.parse('country_data.xml')
 root2 = tree2.getroot()

 type(root1)
 <type 'Element'>

 type(root2)
 <class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>
```

May be because of this difference, it fails with error as mentioned in 
[Using ElementTree works but not with cElementTree , throws TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46079107/using-elementtree-works-but-not-with-celementtree-throws-typeerror)

Please try to help how to resolve this issue...

Thanks in advance